# Plants growth rate

Tags: growth

I'm making a  "device" to plant some vegetables, and I would find more than useful to know what growth/time equation plants follow. It is linear?, or do some plants growth exponentially?.

Not sure where to ask this question, any links will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This question needs much clarification - different plants grow at different rates, so not knowing which plant makes it practically impossible to answer, and all plants grow only as well as the conditions they're growing in - in other words, if they're growing in unsuitable soil or don't get enough root room/light/feed/air/water, then different results will occur.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm going to grow the plants in an hydroponic controlled environment, so expect maximum growth without any problems. About the different plants growing at a different rate, I'm not talking about the relative speed between plants, I can manage that, but the relative speed in their own growth life. To make it simpler, do plants grow X cms/day or do their growth depends on their stage?.

Comment: As I don't know whether Plant X is a carrot, Livingstone daisy or a tree fern, its still impossible to answer.

Comment: Lettuce for example.

Comment: Under optimum conditions, lettuce will germinate and grow to a croppable point within 2-4 weeks, though it depends to some extent on which variety of lettuce.

Comment: That is not what I asked, what I need to know is what how plants growth over time. An example, a lettuce will grow 3 cms in the first 10 days after seeding, and then 20 cms in the following 12 days. As you can see, the "growth equation" is not linear, it depends on the stage of the plant.

Comment: Well, maybe someone else can give you a formulaic answer - all I know is, take 4 lettuce plants, grown in the same conditions, germinated at the same time, 2 will romp away, one is a bit slower and one seems to be the 'runt of the litter' so to speak; or, all 4 grow at the same rate. That's how it is with living things, nothing's that certain.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Biology, not gardening/landscaping as defined in the help center.